# SQL Server entity tables and storedproc automation tools?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

Are there any automation tools to ease creation of tables and adding standard insert/select/update stored procs, rather than doing hand creation for a large number of tables ?

If i have 100 tables to create (and later ALTER) and their associated stored procs in SQL Server 2008, what is the most convenient way to do it ?

**ADDED:**

1. Are there tools to auto-generate nice class skeletons (with data fields) tied-up with corresponding tables ?

I am using C# .NET 4.0 in Visual studio 2010 and Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

We are starting off a new project from scratch, so it would be helpful to get tools for quick bootstrap from Design on paper to initial code.

Any other related suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Consider the possibility that you may not need stored procs. The kind of stored proc which could be generated by a tool can be replaced by the SQL automatically generated by Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SSMS Database Diagrams to design you 100 tables because one only has to type the column name and can point and click for data type, primary key, nullability, foreign key, etc.  Create a diagram for each functional grouping.  When the design is done you can write a script which will write the SQL for the stored proc to do the insert/update for the tables.

As you create the script to write the script you could post your work here.

Comment: thnx rc_cleland, will try it out and post the resulting.